# Are there any philosophers associated with phenomenology and existentialism that argue that death should not matter to an individual?

Tags: existentialism, death, heidegger, phenomenology, being-and-time

I have mainly been focussing upon Heidegger in relation to death and the way in which he believes it is of great importance because in order to live authentically one must 'be-towards-death'. surley there are those that think that death should not matter in such a way? or better yet, contend that it shouldn't and doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Phenomenology and existentialism are mostly about what *is* and not about what *ought* or *should* be. It is likely that people who argue that way would not  be meaningfully associated to these currents.

Comment: In [this](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/46256/28067) answer there briefly mentioned is that for Sartre, own death is not "my possibility", which is disagreement with Heidegger. In Being and Nothingness, there is chapter "My death".

Comment: For H., Nothingness (non-Being) is associated with death, and we become free from nonauthenticity and can be able to listen Being (which is "human" Dasein) when faced with death and thank to it. For S., Nothingness is associated with everyday freedom-in-life (though we can fathom it deep mainly in a crisis-of-decision), while death is associated with Being (which is inert for S.) and does not lead, itself, to authenticity.